# Почему нельзя установить смену раскладки клавиатуры на alt+shift стандартными средствами?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например если прожать alt+shift+d то принимает, а просто alt+shift нет. В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Филосовский вопрос. Скорее всего связанно с глобальным отловом комбинаций клавиш при методе ввода отличном от xkb+xinput, переходом на wayland, модными изоляциями приложений друг от друга в snap, flatpack, pipewire и т.п.

[Вот пример проблемы](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473)

Комбинация может быть выставленна в стандартном средстве настройки gnome-tweak. Этот раздел за последние 5 лет пару раз кочевал из "настроек" в "дополнительные настройки" и обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]